# Deserialise Dictionary<string, object> with Newtonsoft and C#

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to parse a Json response which come from a server.
I manage to recreate the server response and I can parse this response with Newtonsoft.
My issue come with my Dictionary of (string, JSONNode) which is my base class for all my parsed object.

Here is my code

```cs
[Serializable]
public class JSONNode
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Cache : JSONNode
{
    public Dictionary<string, JSONNode> Elements { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Parking : JSONNode
{
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class House : JSONNode
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Car : JSONNode
{
    public JSONNode Back { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var Cache = new Cache()
    {
        Type = "Cache",
        Id = "Cache",
        Elements = new Dictionary<string, JSONNode>() {
            {"Parking", new Parking(){
            Type = "Parking",
            Id = "Parking",
            Cars = new List<Car>(){
                new Car(){
                Type="MyType1",
                Id = "3",
                Back = null},
                new Car(){
                Type="MyType2",
                Id = "3",
                Back = null}}
                }
            },
            {"House", new House(){
                Type="House",
                Id="House",
                Number=156}
            }
        }
    };
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Cache);
    var jsonSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
    {
    TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
    };
    var reCache = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cache>(json, jsonSettings);
}
```

Is there a way to parse this kind of information with Newtonsoft ? I need this library as it is compatible with Unity and I will need it later.

**Edit** : As I thought, there is no way to parse smartly a Dictionary. As a Workaround, I used a JSON parser (like [SimpleJSON](https://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#)) to parse my data as a tree.

Answer (score 0):

*most (from my experience) JSON serializers can only handle Dictionary as long as they are dealing with primitive (and string) key/values, in other words no you'd have to either build your own handler or return 2 seperate lists.

This would work:

```
var Cache = new Cache()
{
    Type = "Cache",
    Id = "Cache",
    ElementKeys = new List<string> {
        {"Parking", "House" };
    ElementValues = new List<JSONNode>{
        new Parking(){
        Type = "Parking",
        Id = "Parking",

        Cars = new List<Car>(){
            new Car(){
            Type="MyType1",
            Id = "3",
            Back = null},
            new Car(){
            Type="MyType2",
            Id = "3",
            Back = null}}
            },
        new House(){
        Type="House",
        Id="House",
        Number=156}

    }
 };
```

You'd have to change your `Cache` class like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Cache : JSONNode
{
    public List<string> ElementKeys { get; set; }
    public List<JSONNode> ElementValues { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: From which namespace did you get your ElementKeys and ElementValues ?

Comment: it''s just a name, I guess I'd have to change the `Cache` class, I will update my answer.

Comment: The bad part is you have to keep both lists in sync.  You could always keep the dictionary property as a non serialized property and then add methods to create the 2 lists....

Comment: The fact is that I cannot change the server's Json as it's not my server and data.
I guess I'll have to found another library which is compatible with Unity3D and who can do such thing